# How can I refrence a method from one library's dependency library in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Assuming that I build a `LibraryA` and compile it into a `LibA.jar`, then I create a `LibraryB` and put the generated `LibA.jar` into `LibraryB/libs`, and compile it into a `LibB.jar`.

The problem is, as I put `LibB.jar` into a new Android App Module, I can not directly reference methods in `LibA.jar`. Looks like I can only reference methods in `LibB.jar`, but the `LibB.jar` is compiled with a `LibA` dependency. Is there any way I can walk through this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all source code access to `LibraryA` and `LibraryB`, you can simply solve it by making `LibraryA` as a seperated module for `LibraryB`. So when you want to include `LibraryB` in a project, you must include `LibraryA` too.

If `LibraryA` is hidden in `LibraryB` for external use, you can make a public method where you can get the `LibraryA` from `LibraryB`, something like `getLibraryA().methodA1()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .aar to wrap the library. The format of .aar allows to "embed" dependencies inside. There is a [Gradle lib on GitHub](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) that helps with this. If you use Maven repos, the POM file for LibraryB can describe its dependency LibraryA.